# List of all netsh error codes?

Tags: c#, netsh

Is there a full listing of error codes that netsh can produce?
I'm not turning up very much on google, and the  [documentation for netsh that I have found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307236(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to only include usage/parameter information, not error codes.

What I'm trying to do is add some simple GUI actions to a configuration tool for a product, to streamline the process of registering SSL ports and urls (for a windows service which uses the OWIN HttpListener).  I'd like to provide some less cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just call the [HTTP.sys API for SSL configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364649(v=vs.85).aspx) directly.  `netsh` is almost undoubtedly calling [`HttpSetServiceConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364503(v=vs.85).aspx) and returning the result directly.

There is a [utility on Codeplex](http://httpsysmanager.codeplex.com/) which provides a managed wrapper around the HTTP.sys API.

[image: Example of a utility managing the same thing as netsh]

Answer (score 0):

This a reference I use frequently [Windows Command Line](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NF5JMS8)

and here's another reference that i check sometimes: [SS64](http://ss64.com/)